# Connect to Tor Bridge running on Google Cloud

Tags: configuration, torsocks, pluggable-transports, obfs4

I deployed a Tor Bridge on Google Cloud. I can connect to the bridge from my local machine(Tor Browser on the local machine) using this -

```
<Googe cloud ip>:9001
```

9001 is ORPort on Google cloud.

Now, I want to use pluggable transport and I build it using this repository - https://github.com/Yawning/obfs4

Placed obfsproxy file in /usr/local/bin/obfsproxy

This is my torrc file which is on Google cloud

```
Exitpolicy reject *:*
RunAsDaemon 1
ORPort 9001
BridgeRelay 1
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/local/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:443
ExtORPort auto
ContactInfo <Email Address>
Nickname <name>
PublishServerDescriptor 0
ControlPort 9051
CookieAuthentication 1
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
```

Now when I tried to connect to the bridge by placing this line in torrc line at my local machine-

/tor-browser_en-US/Browser/TorBrowser/Data/Tor/torrc

```
obfs4 <Google cloud ip>:9001 fingerprint iat-mode=0
```

I am not able to connect to the bridge now, Also I wasn't sure about the ORPort so I used this as well -

```
obfs4 <Google cloud ip>:443 fingerprint iat-mode=0
```

443 -> Port for pluggable transport.

Errors I get ->

```
[WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to <Googe cloud ip>:9001 ("general SOCKS server failure")
[NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.
```

Please let me know what I am doing wrong here and how can I connect to bridge(with obfs4) because without obfs4 I am able to connect without having any problem.